Create a Sparse vector from Pyspark dataframe maintaing the index
I have pyspark df like this:
+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
|             user_id|game_id|3mon_views|3mon_carts|3mon_trans|3mon_views|      dt|
+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0418034|       1.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0501080|       0.0|       1.0|       0.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0601010|       3.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0602002|       0.0|       2.0|       0.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0603006|       0.0|       0.0|       5.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0605004|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       1.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0608002|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       2.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0608006|       0.0|       0.0|       2.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0608007|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       4.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0611004|       0.0|       1.0|       0.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0614001|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       1.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0614008|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       2.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|0615007|       9.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|1101004|      10.0|       0.0|      15.0|       0.0|20230813|
|0006e38c8968431f8...|1101007|       0.0|       0.0|       5.0|       3.0|20230813|
+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+

where for given user_id, game_id and given dt we have 4 features  3mon_views|3mon_carts|3mon_trans|3mon_views. We have total 1000 unique game_id
Now I want to create a sparse matrix of user_id for given dt which will have all the features for that users corresponding to that game if feature for that game_id is present in user or else it'll be 0. So over sparse vector will be of shape (4*1000, ), Now how can I create a sparse matrix after grouping by user, dt and maintain index for that game_id, for example 10th index in sparse vector will belong to specifc game_id, feature combination, like each index will belong to specifc game_id, feature pair and value will be the score from the dataframe if exist or 0.
Result df:
user_id | sparsefeat_vec | dt


Can you post a sample expected output?
